# Getting Classes in red color with out syntactical errors in Android studio

Tags: android

I was trying to rename project packages by ctrl+shift+r command to new name. Observed the classes red color as indicate in the screenshot and after that when I tried to install App in real device it is not getting installed.

Does anybody had issue like this?

[image]

Comment: I think the red color means they are not added to whatever versioning system you are using.

Comment: @BakonJarser that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not issue. But if you make commit this files do note save. You need to add they to you git. Just move you cursor to file and turright click and find add to git in popup. Or you can add all files in the same time. Just move you cursor to root package "app" and make add git from menu popup after mouth right click. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Java classes between packages can only be used if you import the package into the class.

So you have to modify the class import by changing the package name just rename.

My level in English is relatively low I hope you understand correctly.